# React: Unable to render component

Tags: reactjs

Hi guys I am new to React .Just want to render my component into app component but unable to do so here is my code :

conditionalView.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export class conditionalView extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Conditional View</h2>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default conditionalView
```

App.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Bike from './bike';
import Car from './car';
import FnEvent from './FnEvent';
import ClsEvent from './ClsEvent';
import ClsEventBind from './ClsEventBind';
import conditionalView from './conditionalView';
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        {/* <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <Bike name="Caliber 125"  />
        <Car name="Maruti 800"  /> */}
       {/* <FnEvent />
       <ClsEvent /> */}
        {/* <ClsEventBind /> */}
       <conditionalView />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import reactDom from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
reportWebVitals();
```

Basically i want to render content of conditionView.js component into App.js but it is not picking up the content.

Comment: In your conditionalVIew component you wrote two times export remove "export" before "class"
Then check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In react custom components are supposted to start with `capital letters`. For standard HTML elements, like `div`, `span` use lower case.

Also, no need to export twice from `ConditionalView`.

You can export at the same time of declaration along with the `default` keyword.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class conditionalView extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Conditional View</h2>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your component should be PascalCase: ConditionalView, not conditionalView.

Answer (score 0):

React components should always start with a capital letter, so rename `<conditionalView />` to `<ConditionalView />`,

and update the import statement too;
`import ConditionalView from './conditionalView';`

Comment: Your welcome, its a common mistake when your just starting out in React, welcome to the journey and keep persisting, you will get there in the time bro :)

Fyi, a great channel to help you learn the fundamentals of React I reccomend is Net Ninja on YT https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j942wKiXFu8&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9gZD-Tvwfod2gaISzfRiP9d

Also use Visual Studio Code Editor, its a great free tool for coding and supports loads of plugins too.

Comment: thanks man i will follow this tutorial too . Actually i am new to react not programming so i know about vs code

Comment: That's good to hear, so you understand programming logic, which will help you allot with React too :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening because you are exporting component more than once

```
  export class conditionalView extends Component {
```

remove the  export keyword from here